# Outlook mail message into excel using VBA

Tags: outlook, automation

[Excel File Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIQLedQPrPs)

This is a code from an you-tube video. The below code is giving an Compiler error : Userdefined Type not defined.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, Subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

'Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
'Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = what_address
olMail.Subject = Subject_line
olMail.body = mial_body
olMail.send
End Sub

Sub SendMassEmail()
row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
Dim mail_body_message As String
Dim full_name As String
Dim Promoscode As String

mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("J2")
full_name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number) & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
promo_code = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
mial_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)

Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A1" & row_number), "This is a test e-mail", mail_body_message)

Loop Until row_number = 6

End Sub
```

I am having an compiler error, I have checked everything but...not sure what is cousing this issue.

Comment: Debugging would have highlighted "mial_body" in olMail.body = mial_body.

Comment: No this is not getting me olMail.To = what_address

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865320(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class to specify the recipients instead of the [To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860378(v=office.15).aspx) property.

The Recipients class provides the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866951(v=office.15).aspx) method which allows to create and add a new recipient to the collection. Then use the [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862796(v=office.15).aspx) method to attempt to resolve a Recipient object against the Address Book.

```
Sub AssignTask()  
  Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem  
  Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient 
  Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)  
  MyItem.Assign  
  Set myDelegate = MyItem.Recipients.Add("DL name")  
  myDelegate.Resolve  
  If myDelegate.Resolved Then  
    myItem.Subject = "Prepare Agenda For Meeting"  
    myItem.DueDate = Now + 30  
    myItem.Display  
    myItem.Send  
  End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: My code is working perfect, but the only problem is the message body. I need to edit message before sending email. Now it is not allowing me to edit message body.

Comment: Yes! User defined type not defined...I am using code from a youtube video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIQLedQPrPs

Comment: Line 1 Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, Subject_line As String, mail_body As String) "olApp As New Outlook.Application" error as Compiler Error: User Defined Type not defined